# Can we demonstrate that the Quran is perfectly preserved?

Tags: quran, history, preservation

I want you guys to prove it to me that the Quran is perfectly preserved. When I say this, I mean I want you to prove it to me that there is an absolute 0% chance that any verse/surah was removed, lost, added or altered since Muhammad (s.a.w.) passed away.

I want you to convince me that every single ayah that was revealed to Muhammad is in our Quran today in its perfect form.

Use as many sources as you like. They must all be **authentic** and **unambiguous**.

And please don't misinterpret my motif for this question. I'm not bashing Islam. I'm just trying to increase my imaan. So please don't take this the wrong way.

Comment: This can't be proven more than it has been done in several posts you've asked in this site yourself as there are statements of some sects and sahaba pretending that such and such verse or surah have been removed or that this verse has been part of the Quran at a time etc. The Quran in his final version however is approaved by the ummah we can't say more than that.

Comment: Salam, I have wrote an answer. I would like to know if that solved your problem.

Comment: Do you believe the holocaust took place? Can you prove it? If you can't, does it mean it never took place?

Comment: Brother, I would recommend to just put these thoughts away, eventually, it will lead you to a path that is too far away from Allah, we all believe in God although no one has ever see him, we believe that Muhamed is the messenger of Allah, but no one living now has ever seen him. The belief is based on believing not doubting. I have a friend who doubted everything and follow a rule that everything is a lie till you prove it to me, Now he is more to an atheist  than a Muslim

Comment: @Kilise When I said "prove it", I meant it from a historical perspective. In other words, you have to use authentic sources of Islamic history to prove it.

Comment: What I an trying to point out is that even though someone or the majority of people/scholars do say or "prove" that the Quran is perfectly preserved, there will always be some guy saying it isn't and he will have his "proofs". This is true to everything.  Even though we believe the holocaust took place and there are much evidence for that there are still people saying no it never happened. One would first examine these people. Who are they and why do they say it never happened. If they turn out to hate Jews, that might be a good hint for one to reason about their claims.

Comment: Kilise has a point (Mulsim) historical sources all are in consensus about the revelation, the last presentation (al-'arda al-Akhira) or recitation in front of the Prophet (which with historical certainty Zaid ibn Thabet has been part of), the first collection at the time of Abu Bakr and the 2nd at the time of 'Othmane all of this has been covered in former answers (some of them to your Questions). So I don't understand why you insist on a "new" answer?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Because I feel like the method that Zayd ibn Thabit used for the first mushaf had some flaws. I know we've talked about it before but I just can't believe it with a whole heart.

Comment: @HaithamShaddad I wish I could put these thoughts away. But nobody is answering my question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36204/if-a-muslim-has-doubts-can-he-treat-it-as-waswas

Comment: @curiosity be aware that we want to help but you seem to hide information, seem to be hasty with answers, seem not to be clear about your questions ... and finally that maybe we just are not able to help especially if we can't get a feedback or we just have not the necessary knowledge I'd prefer not to say anything instead of saying something wrong or which might cause harm!

Comment: @curiosity  I have answered on that question.

Comment: @Kilise, This is beside the point but there are several non-mainstream research organizations who have gathered tons of material and evidences that apparently contradict the mainstream Holocaust story. Example: http://holocausthandbooks.com/

Comment: @infatuated That is what I said. But even though they have their "evidences" and they found "contradictions". It is not our expertise to know that for sure. And surely there are arguments against their claims. In the meantime the whole world believes the holocaust took place.  What I was trying to explain for him is that even things like the holocaust is being questioned and that wasnt even 100 years ago. But still the majority isn't questioning it. I.e you can question everything in life, there will always be evidences for and against.

Comment: @Kilise, So what you are suggesting is that we can never know the truth! Right? But I don't agree with that! Finding truth imho takes four things: 1) passion, 2) determination 3) courage to question any and all conventions which inevitably involves (often a lot of) 4) risk! That's seemingly what the Supreme Truth tells us in the Book of Truth in 103:3 revealed to a Man of Truth who risked His whole life to tell us the Truth!

Comment: @infatuated No not exactly. But there are circumstances when you never will KNOW the truth. But in other cases when one can argue that one "can know" the truth, it doesn't mean everyone got that skill to know. Somethings needs tens of years of experience to be able to "know". So, if one should live his life listening to the people who argue against mainstream beliefs, he won't be able to do much in his life. You can find arguments against everything. Do you want to prove them all? Do you got the skills to do so? Are you willing to spend 10 years doing so? This is my point.

Comment: @infatuated This is also why I said; "One would first examine these people. Who are they and why do they say it never happened. If they turn out to hate Jews, that might be a good hint for one to reason about their claims"...

Comment: @infatuated Yeah, everybody arent' like you. Many people do just read one or two arguments about topics and are then convinced. Not everyone want to put years of time. And skills are required too, not everybody do got the skills. Also the holocaust was just an example. Yeah, lets end this.

Comment: @Kilise Prophet Muhammad (sa) said: 1) Seek knowledge even if it is to be found in China. Indeed, the pursuit of knowledge is an obligation for all Muslims. / رسول الله (ص): اُطلُبوا العِلمَ ولَو بِالصِّینِ ؛ فإنَّ طَلَبَ العِلمِ فَریضَةٌ عَلى کُلِّ مُسلِم
2) Seek knowledge from cradle to grave. / اطْلُبُوا الْعِلْمَ مِنَ الْمَهْدِ إِلَى اللَّحْد

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Quran really preserved or are there missing parts of the Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/is-the-quran-really-preserved-or-are-there-missing-parts-of-the-quran)

Answer (score 3):

According to currently available evidence, it can't be proven that the Quran is perfectly preserved. And it can't be disproved either. There is not enough evidence available for what you are asking. In Islam, we believe in Allah which is not proven, we believe in angels which isn't proven and we believe in a lot that isn't proven. They aren't proven with scientific evidence, but we believe in them because they logically make sense.

Allah said in the Quran:

> This is the Book about which there is no doubt, a guidance for those
>   conscious of Allah -
>
> **Who believe in the unseen,** establish prayer, and spend out of what We have provided for them,

If there was prove of all the things said in the Quran, then Islam wouldn't be a religion. It would have been recognized as facts by scientists and all people of earth would have believed it.

Comment: Excellent! This is the most correct view! We can't be fairer than this!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you stated "I'm just trying to increase my imaan." in your question is a very precious thing and it is also something I had done a lot and continue to do when I think of Allah, Islam and Quran related topics.

I have no personal information or observation to prove that Quran we have today is what Quran was at our Prophet's time (I honestly don't think any information or "proof" you can find will satisfy you). We can't even prove 100% that a novel of Tolstoy is exactly the same as it was published just one and a half century ago. Not because it can't be proven, but we simply don't have the information and technology required for it. However I have a very important thing to stick to: I believe in everything that's said in Quran with my full heart, though I still think deeply about some verses to understand them better.

What I understand from **Verse 9 of Surah 15** is that Quran is and will be protected by Allah. Once I accept and believe in that, then there remains no doubt for me whether Quran was ever changed or not.

Human psychology usually requires visual, touchable evidence, especially in belief related topics (even some prophets asked Allah to show them something to satisfy their hearts - **Verse 2:260**), but what is so precious about belief is that we believe without having all the evidences, proof we require. Believing in Allah won't matter at one moment, you know what that moment is? The Judgment Day, where everyone will be provided with the evidence they needed, but it will be too late to believe as it has no meaning anymore.

My answer may not be the answer you seek but I recommend that you read Quran again and again, especially the first verse I mentioned, so that some of your questions may be answered in time by Allah's own words.

Answer (score -2):

if you ask one by one hafidz/hafidzah (the memorizer of Qur'an)
there's no difference of Qur'an about their memorizes