# Why is it الرسولا and السبيلا and not الرسول and السبيل in 33:66 and 33:67

Tags: quran, arabic, uloom-al-quran

In these two verses Allah says:

> The Day their faces will be turned about in the Fire, they will say, "How we wish we had obeyed Allah and obeyed the Messenger." ([33:66](http://legacy.quran.com/33/66))
>
> يَوْمَ تُقَلَّبُ وُجُوهُهُمْ فِى النَّارِ يَقُولُونَ يلَيْتَنَآ أَطَعْنَا اللَّهَ وَأَطَعْنَا الرَّسُولاَ

while the -to me- correct wording would be:

> يَوْمَ تُقَلَّبُ وُجُوهُهُمْ فِى النَّارِ يَقُولُونَ يلَيْتَنَآ أَطَعْنَا اللَّهَ وَأَطَعْنَا الرَّسُولَ

and

> And they will say, "Our Lord, indeed we obeyed our masters and our dignitaries, and they led us astray from the [right] way. ([33:67](http://legacy.quran.com/33/67))
>
> وَقَالُواْ رَبَّنَآ إِنَّآ أَطَعْنَا سَادَتَنَا وَكُبَرَآءَنَا فَأَضَلُّونَا السَّبِيلَا

where the -to me- correct wording should be:

> وَقَالُواْ رَبَّنَآ إِنَّآ أَطَعْنَا سَادَتَنَا وَكُبَرَآءَنَا فَأَضَلُّونَا السَّبِيلَ

Note that all verses before and after these two verses end with نَصِيراً, كَبِيراً , سَعِيراً , قَرِيباً and so on. With a few exception one may even say all verses of the whole surah al-Ahzaab end in this style.

This sounds to me like these two words (nouns in ma'arifa form) were put to fit in the poetic license of those nouns in a nakriah form (adjectives)...

Is this addressed somewhere or is there any explanation for this or am I simply wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The verses that you quoted are two out of seven *alifs* that have the same conditions and recitations, commonly known as *al-Alifāt as-Sab'ah* (Arabic: الألفات السبعة) in the topic related to starting and stopping (Arabic: علم الوقف والابتداء) under the science and rules of *tajwīd* (recitation) of the Qur'an (Arabic: أحكام التجويد), and are specific to the qirā'ah of Āssim (Arabic: عاصم) and the ruwāyah of Hafṣ (Arabic: حفص).

In the [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/46749) to the [question on manuscripts](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46748) of the Qur'an, the rule is:

> مذهب الأصوليين وفقهاء المذاهب الأربعة والمحدثين والقراء: أن التواتر شرط في صحة القراءة، ولا تثبت بالسند الصحيح غير المتواتر، ولو وافقت رسم المصاحف العثمانية، وهو قول محدث لا يعول عليه، ويؤدي إلى تسوية غير القرآن بالقرآن
>
> <sub>*— **NOTE**: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> The school of the scholars of the principles [of jurisprudence] and the jurists of the four schools of jurisprudence and the scholars of hadith and the scholars of recitation that [*tawātur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#Mutawatir) (successive narration) is a condition of a correct recitation; what is not *mutawatir* even when authentic is not proof, even if a recitation [that is not *mutawatir*] matches a manuscript of the 'Uthmanic mus'hafs, ass this would be an innovation that cannot be taken into account, as it would be equating non-Qur'an with Qur'an.
>
> <sub>— [Muqaddimāt fi 'Ilm al-Qirā'at, pp. 71](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32485/65)</sub>

The way the words are written in these seven verses is to conform to the recitation. These seven *alifs* have the following characteristics:

- Pronounced as *alif* when stopping on them (unlike a *fat'ha*, which becomes silent at a stopping position), and silent (treated as a regular *fat'ha*) when joining them with the next verse.
- The following letter is a *mutaḥarrik* (Arabic: متحرك) letter, not a *sākin* (Arabic: ساكن) letter.
- Its conjugation is an elongated zero (Arabic: صفر مستطيل), which I highlighted in green to show its 'Uthmanic scripting technique.

The two verses you quoted are:

- [Qur'an 33:66](https://quran.com/33/66/):

[image: Qur'an 33:66]

- [Qur'an 33:67](https://quran.com/33/67/):

[image: Qur'an 33:67]

However, the same rule applies to four other verses:

- [Qur'an 18:38](https://quran.com/18/38/)

[image: Qur'an 18:38]

- [Qur'an 33:10](https://quran.com/33/10/)

[image: Qur'an 33:10]

- [Qur'an 76:4](https://quran.com/76/4/)

[image: Qur'an 76:4]

- [Qur'an 76:15](https://quran.com/76/15/)

[image: Qur'an 76:15]

The seventh *alif* is not really in one verse; rather, it is in 60 (out of 67) times where the pronoun *ana* (Arabic: أنا) is mentioned in the Qur'an, for instance:

- [Qur'an 2:258](https://quran.com/2/258/)

[image: Qur'an 2:258]

- [Qur'an 7:12](https://quran.com/7/12/)

[image: Qur'an 7:12]

Worth noting that the reason seven occurrences bear different ligatures is based on a grammar rule that *al-alif* (Arabic: الألف), *al-wāw* (Arabic: الواو) and *al-yā'* (Arabic: الياء), when are in state of *maddiyyah* (Arabic: الألف والواو والياء المدية) at the end of a word when followed by a *sākin* (Arabic: ساكن), they are joined by *hamzat wasl* (Arabic: همزة وصل) as it is a point of two *sākin* letters following each other, which is the case of the other seven verses with *ana*. This is similar to [pronouncing a non-existing "r" in between two vowels](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/177430) in the English language.

Comment: Even if other qira'at have differences to Hafs the letters -the rasm- and recitation is more or less the same see for example [Qalun 'an Nafi'](http://live.islamweb.net/quran_list/qaloon/s33.pdf) or [Qunbul 'an ibn Kathir](http://live.islamweb.net/quran_list/qunbol/s33.pdf) so it is clearly not a single case of one qira'a. And in Arabic the alif is not necessary nor would it be correct in a normal sentence.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, yes, at large, it is not related to only one *ruwayah* or *qira'ah*, e.g., this is not the case for 76:4, but getting into all possibilities will not fit in a single answer. The *alif* in the verses you inquired about are essential to get the correct recitation, otherwise, they would be read as "sa-beel" (not "sa-bee-la") and "ra-sool" (not "ra-soo-la") without the *alif*. The key point is the writing reflects the recitation.