# What should I do about OCD difficulties leading to lack of focus during prayer?

Tags: salat, medical

I struggle finishing sallah due to not being able to focus (not on purpose) when people are talking. And I make mistakes and sallah takes me hours a day to finish due to repeating over and over. No matter how hard I try I can not pray while people talk. What should I do?

Comment: Try specifying your problem more clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a muslim has doubts, can he treat it as waswas?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36204/if-a-muslim-has-doubts-can-he-treat-it-as-waswas)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution can be to pray as it is recommended in a congregation or at least try to pray almost all your prayers in  a congregation.

> "If the people knew the reward for pronouncing the Adhan and for standing in the first row (in congregational prayers) and found no other way to get that except by drawing lots they would draw lots, and if they knew the reward of the Zuhr prayer (in the early moments of its stated time) they would race for it (go early) and if they knew the reward of `Isha' and Fajr (morning) prayers in congregation, they would come to offer them even if they had to crawl." (sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/13))

As in this case you should follow the Imam and he is the first to be accountable about the lead prayer. (See also: [How to read the 5 salahs in the mosque behind the imam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34863/how-to-read-the-5-salahs-in-the-mosque-behind-the-imam))

You should also gain knowledge on your religion and especially on the prayer to know what you need to do, what you are recommended to do and what you shouldn't do etc. this knowledge might help you fight your OCD.

You should also try to pray in a room where you feel far away from any disturbance!

Please note: I'm no expert on OCD and far away from understanding this issue well enough, but I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

I am in no way expert in OCD consulting but perhaps you can try a few tips to overcome the problem:

1. try finding a quiet place to pray or use earplugs
2. try focusing on the meaning of what you are reciting (in your native language)

If you are not able to despite trying, you should know that:

> God does not charge a soul with more than it can bear. [[2:286]](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/2:286)

You should try your best to complete the prayer *without* repeating and entrust the rest to God.

> "Our Lord, do not take us to task if we forget or make a mistake! Our
>   Lord, do not place on us a burden like the one You placed on those
>   before us! Our Lord, do not place on us a burden we have not the
>   strength to bear! Pardon us; and forgive us; and have mercy on us. You
>   are our Lord and Sustainer, so help us against those who deny the
>   truth." [[2:286]](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/2:286)