# Question about the time frame between prayers?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

For example, if Dhuhr prayer starts at 11:30am and ends at Asr prayer 3:00pm, so the time frame for Dhuhr prayer is 3 hours and a half. Some people say that offering Dhuhr prayer earlier in this time frame is better than offering it in the middle or near the end of the time frame. Some other people say it's ok to offer the prayer any time during the time frame because the rewards will be the same as offering it earlier.

So my question is, which is true?

I usually pray Dhuhr in the middle of the time frame (around 1:45pm).

(Please don't link me to another question and call it 'duplicate'. There is no other question like this one. I've done my research and there is no answer out there. So please help me, thank you).

Comment: Duplicate is when there's an answer out there for this question and there certainly was in the given cases. If you think it is not you should edit those posts instead of posting a new one and making clear what you miss in the provided answers.

Comment: Why do you think [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38423/what-should-i-do-about-ocd-difficulties-leading-to-lack-of-focus-during-prayer/38449?r=SearchResults#38449) doesn't answer it?

Comment: @Medi1Saif The Hadith you quoted in the linked answer exactly answers this question. I was referring to that.

Comment: So according to the Hadith in the link praying dhuhr in the earlier time frame is better. Ok that's all I wanted to know. Thank you.