# Will Allah accept my prayers if I'm distracted by bad thoughts due to mental illness?

Tags: salat, waswasa, sick

I am suffering from one mental disorder called [obsessive-compulsive disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) (OCD).

My main problem is when I start doing salah, I frequently get bad thoughts and bad words in my mind. I never mean those thoughts, but they only come when I start praying. My psychiatrist diagnosed it is one form of OCD, for which I am taking medication.

I am praying all the time but these bad thoughts disturb my prayers. Will Allah accept my prayers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a muslim has doubts, can he treat it as waswas?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36204/if-a-muslim-has-doubts-can-he-treat-it-as-waswas)

Answer (score 1):

Wasak wr wb Simak,

May Allah ease you of your OCD.

Bad or distracting thoughts in salaat are from the shaitan.

> Uthman b. Abu al-'As reported that he came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
>   and said:
>
> Allah's Messenger, the Satan intervenes between me and my prayer and
>   my reciting of the Qur'an and he confounds me. Thereupon **Allah's
>   Messenger (ﷺ) said:, That is (the doing of a) Satan (devil) who is
>   known as Khinzab, and when you perceive its effect, seek refuge with
>   Allah from it and spit three times to your left. I did that and Allah
>   dispelled that from me**.
>
> [Sahih Muslim 2203](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/39/92)

Khushoo is an important part of any prayer.

-Start with concentration during the wudu.
-During salah, think about what you are saying and doing.
-Pondering over the meanings of the Quran ayahs, dhikr and du’as
-Bear in mind that you are conversing with Allah as if you can see Him.

**[Waswasa](https://wikiislam.net/wiki/Waswas)** affects each person differently, because waswasa has to do with a person’s level of doubts and desires and the degree to which a person is attached or fears other things.

If you continue to get bad thoughts or distractions, seek refuge from shaitan (أعوذ بالله من الشيطان الرجيم ) and **dry spit** to your left.

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> Prophet said, "***If anyone of you stands for prayer, he should not spit
>   in front of him because in prayer he is speaking in private to Allah
>   and he should not spit on his right as there is an angel***, but he can
>   spit either on his left or under his left foot and bury it (i.e.
>   expectoration).
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 416](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/8/66)

Also please note that unfortunately lack of concentration during salaats during our times is a very common phenomenon. Your OCD may make it even harder for you but inshallah with explicit concentration and an ever increasing level of imaaan, you will overcome it.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Ive suffered from mental illness for the past 15 years. I am 32 years old now. A lot of my illness had to do with religious ocd. Take it from me, don't worry at all about God not accepting your prayers or about going to Hell or any of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The almighty is the most beneficial & merciful .AS the prayers offering is must at any stage of life but for a man who is ill who is out of order for thats person there are manny coditions for prayers offering .And the person who has mental illness .BY GOD he\she will be forgiven.