# How to handle waswasa?

Tags: salat, waswasa

Everytime I try to pray and whatever is in front of me I get thoughts in my head as if I'm praying to that object and in my head I will argue against it and say that no this is just a wall for example or this is just a chair and it's frustrating me and it's making me lose focus in Salah and I feel like I'm committing a sin (the biggest sin) and I don't know what to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a muslim has doubts, can he treat it as waswas?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36204/if-a-muslim-has-doubts-can-he-treat-it-as-waswas)

Answer (score 0):

i think ruqya sharia everyday, listen to quran everyday will help. use blank non dark color sajjada will help. and dont overthink. i think it also a sign that you should go to mosque everytime pray. be careful some ruqya which is not sharia use some words that consider to make u commit shirk get help from jinn aka blackmagic or mantra. just must do dua of intention of pray. and not worry about such things.